# Hosting nextjs with nodejs as a backend locally

Tags: hosting, router, self-hosting

I have a nextjs as frontend and nestjs as backend MVP project.

I'm hosting this project locally just for presentation for about an hour then im going to shut it down. I have configure my asus router to forward any request to my local IP and its working because my friend can open it from Vietnam to California. The problem is when he tries to login, he cant we get this error. `(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on browser when I inspect. Now my login route on nextjs is still set as `localhost:8000/auth/login` this is where I'm confused because isnt it localhost will just connect to my public IP? or should I change the localhost to my public IP then create another port forwarding profile on my asus router?

Comment: ok I think I know whats wrong now. (Not 100% sure). So on my router I created 2 profile now. 1st for my nodejs backend with set port to 80, 2nd for my nextjs app external port set to 3000, then internal port set to 3000 also. 

The way I understand this is that on my backend I have to change localhost to my public API then, set the port to 80. this will give access to my backend API.

On my frontend I have to connect like this. public_ip:3000 then router will take care of forwarding the routes? anyway Ill test this out and be back.

Comment: Im in now guys. holy fucking shit!! Im feeling good thank thank you. will post answer soon. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a domain name?  If so what is your DNS configuraton?  Are you running a reverse proxy to port 3000 from the main web server?  If so, what is its configuration?  What do your URLs look like?  Are you using relative URLs or are you hard-coding `localhost` into some URLs?

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.